# VB.Net: How to display groupbox on right click?

Tags: vb.net, chromium-embedded

I am making a VB.Net web browser, and to make the whole thing look nice, when the user right clicks, I want a groupbox to show up where the mouse was right clicked. I am using the ChromeWebBrowser.Net project on SourceForge and when I add the following code:

```
Private Sub ChromeWebBrowser1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ChromeWebBrowser1.MouseUp
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        GroupBox1.Location = (e.Location)
        GroupBox1.Visible = True
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

It should be working, but when I test it and right click on the web browser control, it does not show up. When I add the same code to the main forms code, it works fine, it just is not working on the browsing control. No errors or anything, it will just not show up. Is there something special I need to do, or can there be a workaround to this?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this groupbox on top of other controls? If so the control thats behind the groupbox wont allow this as it would need to be added to that controls collection.

Comment: In all what im saying is the groupbox may not just float over another control...

Comment: trying doing `GroupBox1.BringToFront()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, this sounds more like you should be using a ContextMenuStrip. You can drop one onto your form(then add items to it), and finally after that you can set the webbrowser's contextmenustrip property to be the one you just designed.

Comment: I would use a ContextMenuStrip, but I would like to make it look nice by adding picture buttons.